# Litecoin transaction fee

Tags: transactions, litecoin, transaction-fees

I have been struggling over the past few days to get some up-to-date information about Litecoin and I keep ending with nothing.

To start off, I would like the formula that calculates the required fee per transaction.

For Bitcoin, for example, this info is available here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees

Where can I find the same information for Litecoin?

I found this: https://litecoin.info/Transaction_fees among other forum posts but I couldn't find what the value of these factors are:

- Minimum suggested transaction priority
- Number of bytes each input adds to the transaction size
- Number of bytes each output adds to the transaction size

If anyone could share their knowledge or point me to the right direction I would appreciate, after all this search I feel very frustrated.